# How Do I Identify DataGrid Row for Deletion?

Tags: c#, datagrid, crud

I am currently rewriting an old VB.net script of mine in C#. I have a DataGrid and a Delete button in each row. I want to pass a given Id (KeyphraseToBrandId) to the OnDeleteCommand, to delete that row in the database. I am having trouble getting this row identified.

Here is my MyDataGrid_DeleteCommand, which shows all the things I have tried which have not worked, as comments:

```
protected void MyDataGrid_DeleteCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
{

    String connStr = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];

    // Define db connection
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);

    String DeleteSql = "DELETE from KeyphrasesToBrands WHERE KeyphraseToBrandId=?KeyphraseToBrandId";

    MySqlCommand DeleteCommand = new MySqlCommand(DeleteSql, conn);

    // DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add("?KeyphraseToBrandId", MyDataGrid.DataKeys(CInt(E.Item.ItemIndex)));

// This works for Id 8, so it's not the rest of the code        
// DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add("?KeyphraseToBrandId", "8");

    // DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add("?KeyphraseToBrandId", MyDataGrid.SelectedDataKey.Value.ToString());

    // DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add("?KeyphraseToBrandId", MyDataGrid.DataKeys.Equals(e.Item.ItemIndex));

    // DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add("?KeyphraseToBrandId", e.Item.ItemIndex.ToString());

    // DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add("?KeyphraseToBrandId", e.Item.ItemIndex);

        // DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add("?KeyphraseToBrandId", e.CommandArgument.ToString());

        // DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add("?KeyphraseToBrandId", e.Item.Cells[0].ToString());

        DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add("?KeyphraseToBrandId", e.CommandArgument);

        DeleteCommand.Connection.Open();

        DeleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        BindGrid();

        DeleteCommand.Connection.Close();

    }
```

... and here's my DataGrid:

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="MyDataGrid" runat="server" DataKeyField="KeyphraseToBrandId" OnCancelCommand="MyDataGrid_CancelCommand" OnDeleteCommand="MyDataGrid_DeleteCommand" OnSelectedIndexChanged="MyDataGrid_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoGenerateColumns="false">

    <Columns>

            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="KeyphraseText" HeaderText="Keyphrase Text"></asp:BoundColumn> 

            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="BrandName" HeaderText="Brand Name"></asp:BoundColumn>

            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="KeyphraseToBrandId" HeaderText="Keyphrase To Brand Id"></asp:BoundColumn>

            <asp:ButtonColumn ButtonType="PushButton" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" HeaderText="Delete?" />

    </Columns>

</asp:DataGrid>
```

How do I pass KeyphraseBrandId to the delete command, to identify this row for deletion in the database?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete bulk Selected Rows then you can do it

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row  in yourDataGridView.SelectedRows)
{    
     yourDataGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(row.Index);
}
```

This is work as find the index(The identity of Listed Rows in DataGrid). It remove Rows temporary, If you want to remove the data from data base itself, you need to get identity id from Row and delete it or change active status as per your requirement.